# PHP SOAP API - How to pass the parameters and files that needs to be uploaded?

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am new with SOAP Integration. I normally use REST. I have client that uses SOAP API integration. My application us built in PHP. I am having problems passing the required parameters and keeps getting error.

These is what I have tried:

```
class uploadTransactionFileRequest {

function __construct($param1, $param2, $param3, $param4)
{
    $this->bankID = $param1;
    $this->file = $param2;
    $this->fileFormat= $param3;
    $this->type = $param4;
}
}

$client = new SoapClient("https://www.example.com");

$contact = new uploadTransactionFileRequest($param1, $param2, $param3, $param4);
$params = array(
    "contact" => $contact,
    "description" => "Barrel of Oil",
    "amount" => 500,
);

$response = $client->__soapCall('uploadTransactionFileRequest', array($params));
pre_print_r($response);
```

The return of the response is:
 Function ("uploadTransactionFileRequest") is not a valid method for this service detl : SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("uploadTransactionFileRequest") is not a valid method for this service in C:\xampp\htdocs......

And if I use $client->__getTypes();

```
    [14] => struct uploadTransactionFile {
 uploadTransactionFileRequest uploadReq;
}
    [15] => struct uploadTransactionFileRequest {
 base64Binary param1;
 fileName param2;
 boolean param3;
 transactionType param4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `uploadTransactionFile` is the name of the function and `uploadTransactionFileRequest` is the name of the parameter.

Your code should look something like:

```
$response = $client->uploadTransactionFile(
    new uploadTransactionFileRequest(/* ... */)
);
```

`uploadTransactionFile` isn't a method that is already defined on `SoapClient` or a method that you have to define, but a magic method that gets called. It should "just work". Have a look at the PHP docs for `__call()` if you want to know more about that.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call

You can use a tool such as SoapUI to generate XML requests. That can help you understand what your request object should look like.

Comment: Do i need to create uploadTransactionFileRequest() function here in my codes?

I am really new in SOAP. Most of my integrations are done in REST. I would appreciate your response. thank  you.

And do i need to create a .wsdl file?

Comment: The question is, how can I send a request? I need to integrate our system to theirs. And the client sent me a file in a pdf format that contains 3 parts:

The raw POST, the SOAP envelop and the content of the file.

Comment: Have you got a WSDL file or a URL that points to one? The WSDL is the API specification. From if you can find out the names of all the services offered, and what the request and response objects look like.
To actually send a request and get the response, use the code above.